# Responsive table with td which go under one another

Tags: html-table, media-queries, cell, responsive

I want to make my table responsive but I don't know how to use media-queries, can somebody help me? My goal is to make my `td` act like blocks, going under one another if the screen size is smaller.

Current code:

```css
td{border:1px dotted red;background-color:red;color:white;}

p{font-family:'Varela Round';font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>SOCIETES</p></td>
      <td><p>CONTACT</p></td>
      <td><p>EMAIL NOMINATIF</p></td>
      <td><p>OPT OUT</p></td>
      <td><p>LIGNES DIRECTES/MOBILES</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you have to work with Bootstrap frame work then use `<div class='table-responsive' ><table class='table'>....</table></div>`. May be this will be resolve your issue.

Comment: Check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the td from display:block to display:table-cell at a minimum width using media queries for a mobile first approach.

```css
td{
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  border:1px dotted red;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  td{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px dotted red;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:0px;
  }
}


p{font-family:'Varela Round';font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>SOCIETES</p></td>
      <td><p>CONTACT</p></td>
      <td><p>EMAIL NOMINATIF</p></td>
      <td><p>OPT OUT</p></td>
      <td><p>LIGNES DIRECTES/MOBILES</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'll like to know is it possible to put space between each td when it is in a responsive form?

Comment: Ok thank you and I'm still learning but for you I would like to add a link "see more" under each word. Is it better to place an other table in each main td or to place a div ?

Comment: Why not just add a <br> followed by a link to your paragraph tag.